# rails mongoid criteria find by association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, associations, mongoid

I'm trying to find a record by associated username which is included in a belongs_to relation, but it's not working.

Articles belong to Users
Users have many articles

`Article.where(user_id: someid)` works fine, but I'd like to use the username as reference which is stored in the Users table.

```
Article.includes(:user).where(:username => "erebus")
Article.includes(:user).where("user.username" => "erebus")
```

I also have `identity_map_enabled: true`

`Article.includes(:user).inclusions` returns the relation details

Doesn't work, what am I not understanding?

Answer (score 31):

You have to keep in mind that there are no joins in mongodb. In relational dbs, `includes` forms a join query and you can use columns from both the tables in query. However due to absence of joins in mongodb, same is not possible.

In mongoid, `includes` just saves a bunch of db calls. It fetches and stores the associated records in identity map for fast retrieval, but still while querying, one query can only deal with one collection.

If you need articles based on user names, I would suggest following work around:

```
user_ids = User.where(username: 'erebus').only(:_id).map(&:_id)
articles = Article.where(:user_id.in => user_ids)
```

Comment: what if we get the data from the other way and there's actually no array in the current collection, but the other one ?

Comment: oh yes i know the answer : you can't.

Comment: would this not increase the query complexity? what if we what the same result like joins or some alternative solution

Comment: @JaiKumarRajput This is a very outdated solution, mongodb supports join like functionality now, please consult documentation.

Comment: Rubish, can you please suggest me some link or public assets where I can take help?

Comment: Also does mongoid help in same?

Answer (score 16):

You can make it little shorter from what rubish suggested:

```
user_ids = User.where(username: 'erebus').pluck(:id)
articles = Article.where(:user_id.in => user_ids)
```

Or one liner:

```
articles = Article.where(:user_id.in => User.where(username: 'erebus').pluck(:id))
```

Comment: would this not increase the query complexity?
what if we what the same result like joins or some alternative solution